# How to check if the Proxy has been set correctly?

Tags: http, command-line, https, http-proxy

I am setting the proxy on windows using the below command  :

```
set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
set https_proxy=https://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```

How can I verify if it has been set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method using packet capture. Like wireshark.

## First

It can be distinguished by port number.

In general, HTTP used port 80.

However, if you use a different port for your proxy configuration, you can distinguish is as a port number.

## Two

It can be distinguished by HTTP request header.

A request URL using HTTP proxy include full URI. like `GET http://www.kangmj37.com HTTP/1.1`

A request METHOD using HTTPS proxy using `CONNECT`. like `CONNECT www.kangmj37.com:443 HTTP/1.1`. See RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6

> **4.3.6.  CONNECT**
>
> CONNECT is intended only for use in requests to a proxy.

Comment: Anny cmd line cmd?

Comment: @Raulp Try show environment variable. like `echo %http_proxy%`